# How do I integrate a 3rd party non-zend application into my Zend Framework application?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to create a ZF application that also includes Mibew Messenger which offers live chat support to visitors. Ideally I would like it to go through a controller which does some initial setup before redirecting to the non-zend app.

Eg.  http://example.com/support/ goes to the SupportController, the indexAction checks to see if the user is logged in, if so, checks their access and redirects them to either the /mibew/client/index.php or /mibew/operator/index.php of the non-zend application but make it appear to be *example.com/support/client/* or *example.com/support/operator/.*

I'm fairly new to setting up ZF and I'm at a loss as to how I would go about doing this if it is at all possible. Help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm on a shared host, the file system is pretty much vanilla except the root includes a .htaccess and index.php, the .htaccess has only:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

index.php just includes public/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have your controller do whatever handling needed to be done, and you would setup some rewrites in htaccess for the external application to live at.

ie in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule support/client/ mibew/client/index.php
```

you would then do the redirect. Unfortunately you cannot have both the setup script and the final application at the same url without doing something nasty involving frames or similar.